# Shorthand Modal content not working with HTML tags in React Semantic UI

Tags: css, reactjs, styles, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

As mentioned in the [document](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/modal/#types-shorthand), we can create the modal in this shorthand method. But if I add any HTML tags in the `content` section the original style is not retained.

for ex:
Working fine:

```
const ModalExampleShorthand = () => (
  <Modal
    trigger={<Button>Show Modal</Button>}
    header='Reminder!'
    content='Call Benjamin regarding the reports.'
    actions={['Snooze', { key: 'done', content: 'Done', positive: true }]}
  />
)
```

not working (Content section style gone):

```
const ModalExampleShorthand = () => (
  <Modal
    trigger={<Button>Show Modal</Button>}
    header='Reminder!'
    content={<p>Call Benjamin regarding the reports</p>}
    actions={['Snooze', { key: 'done', content: 'Done', positive: true }]}
  />
)
```

You can edit this in the "Try it" section itself [here:](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/modal/#types-shorthand)

Answer (score 0):

This is a common mistake and will be covered in new shorthand docs very soon.

Actual issue: when you passed a React element, it will replace the whole shorthand slot.

Valid usages are:

```
content={<Modal.Content>Call Benjamin regarding the reports.</Modal.Content>}
content={{ content: <p>Call Benjamin regarding the reports.</p> }}
```